Допускается ли обособление оборота с союзом А ТАКЖЕ?
Рассмотрим предложение:
В странах Аравийского полуострова, а также в перечисленных выше странах Восточной Африки, это растение является неотъемлемой частью жизни общества...
Можно ли обособить оборот?
В чем проблема? Союз А ТАКЖЕ считается соединительным в предложениях с однородными членами, там действует правило:
После однородного члена предложения, 
присоединяемого союзом а также или а то и, запятая 
не ставится (т. е. этот однородный член не 
обособляется): Всеобщая грамотность населения, а 
также широкая пропаганда научных знаний должны 
способствовать неуклонному росту культуры в нашей 
стране; 

Проверить это правило на практике сложно, так как  оборот обычно стоит в конце предложения. Предложения со словосочетанием А ТАКЖЕ
Но ведь можно считать, что в приведенном предложении нет однородных отношений, но есть уточняющее или присоединительное обстоятельство.
Так можно ли обособить оборот?
P. S. Вообще говоря меня удивляет дружный хор, утверждающий единственно правильное решение: запятая после оборота не ставится никогда. Выделяется ли запятыми а также? Откуда в людях это беспрекословное послушание и любовь к однозначности? Ведь мы часто делаем выбор между однородными и уточняющими отношениями  § 22. Уточняющие члены предложения
